# UIImageView is resized as per UIImage - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, cgcontext

I am making UIImage from CGIImageRef.

```
  CGImageRef drawImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(croppedImage.CGImage, frame);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:drawImage];
    CGImageRelease(drawImage);
```

And applying it to Image View:

```
 self.imageview.image = newImage;
```

After this line `self.imageview.image = imgV.image;` my imageView is resized to size of `UIImage(newImage)`.

When I log my self.imageview frame then I am getting correct value. I am not able to get exact reason behind this.

Comment: Try self.imageView.layer.maskToBounds = YES, you could see what happen

Comment: @OnikIV doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView will be autoResize to fit its image size if u didnt set the frame of imageView

Comment: I am setting the frame just after applying the image. When I log the image view frame then it is correct. but on view it is not.